# PHP table and code in echo <td>

Tags: php, wordpress, cell

At this moment I am working on a WordPress website. To get the title of the site I am using the next code:

```
<div class="site-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></div>
```

Now I want to put this code/ the result of it in a php table cell, so:

```
echo "<td align='center' width='50%'>SITENAME</td>";
```

How can I implement/ use that php bloginfo code at the place where currently SITENAME is written?

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
echo "<td align='center' width='50%'>".bloginfo( 'name' )."</td>";
```

Comment: Now it ignores align='center' and width='50%' ?

Answer (score 1):

Just echo it like this

```
echo "<td align='center' width='50%'>".bloginfo( 'name' )."</td>";
```

Comment: Now it ignores align='center' and width='50%' ?